# Вывод списка товаров с описанием(цитатой)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется wordpress, на нем установлен wooCommerce.
Необходимо вывести список товаров на произвольной странице так, чтоб к каждому товару выводилась следующая информация:
- Название товара
- Описание (анотация\цитата) товара
- Цена
- Кнопка "подробнее" или что-то в этом духе.(! не добавить в корзину)

Прошу помощи! Сам перелопатил уже все что мог. Сроки горят, я в отчаянии. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: а что не получается-то?

Comment: Не получается вывести анотацию. В вывод идет только заголовок, цена и мета теги(категории). Собственно самый большой вопрос и проблема в анотации.

Comment: как вы всё остальное выводите? приведите пример

Comment: Вывожу через шорткод [products limit=»4″ columns=»2″ visibility=»featured» ]

Comment: предполагаю, что можно решить это иначе, написав свой шорткод, но к сожалению не имею такого опыта. если наведете на хоть какую - то идею о возможной реализации, буду бесконечно вам благодарен!

Comment: собственно реализацию в настоящий момент делаю по шорткодам, нашел вот тут описание имеющихся кодов: https://www.imagecms.net/blog/rukovodstva/shortkody-woocommerce   но опять таки, про анотации там нет ни слова... :(

Comment: добавьте код в functions.php
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/display-product-description-in-product-pages-on-woocommerce/

Comment: О, боги, спасибо вам огромное! Это то, что нужно! Благодарю!

Comment: @Алексей добавьте пожалуйста ваш комментарий, как ответ на тикет. Я его отмечу. Может кому будет тоже полезно и пригодится. Легче найти будет людям, да и вам в карму плюсик =)

Comment: вы можете сами добавить свой вариант, я всего лишь скинул ссылку на пример.

Comment: @Алексей как ответ добавьте ваше решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как тикет нужно закрыть и отметить как "имеющий решение", я возьму инициативу на себя, но оговорюсь, что ответ был дан не мной, а Алексеем выше.
И так, для решения проблемы делаем следующее:
Создаем файл с именем cloudways-product-shor-des.php и размещаем его в свою директорию по адресу wp-content/plugins
Содержимое файла делаем следующим:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Cloudways Display WooCommerce Product Short Description 
 * Description: Add WooCommerce product short description to the loop in product 
archive pages
 * Version: 1.0
*/
function cloudways_short_des_product ( ) { 
    the_excerpt ( ) ;
}
add_action ( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' , 'cloudways_short_des_product' , 40 )
```

Далее активируем появившийся плагин(мы его только что создали)
Этого будет достаточно, чтобы вывести описание товара. Но оно будет достаточно длинным. Если вам требуется сократить кол-во выводимых слов, или просто интересно прочитать первоисточник, дабы расширить свои знания по этой теме, я рекомендую ознакомиться с первоисточником по [ссылке](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/display-product-description-in-product-pages-on-woocommerce/)